# SharePoint 2013 - Master Page not available when editing page layout

Tags: master-page, page-layout

I have downloaded [TheBootstrapTheme](http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/theme/thebootstraptheme) (free version) and have installed and activated it successfully. However when I go to Create a New Page Layout in Design Manager, the master page for this theme isn't available.

Could somebody please explain how I make it available?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a solution to this however my workaround was to make a new page layout (from one of the packaged layouts) using SharePoint Designer.